# MSW and Remix: globalThis.XMLHttpRequest is not a constructor

Tags: remix.run, msw

I've tried setting up MSW in my Remix app by copying a few examples ([This playwright one](https://github.com/cliffordfajardo/remix-msw-node-with-playwright) and the [remix-run example](https://codesandbox.io/p/sandbox/remix-run-examples-msw-9tsqm4?file=%2Fmocks%2Findex.js%3A8%2C1)), but every time I get this error:

```
[mf:err] TypeError: globalThis.XMLHttpRequest is not a constructor
  at checkTypeSupport (../storefront-remix/node_modules/rollup-plugin-node-polyfills/polyfills/http-lib/capability.js:20:11)
  at ../../node_modules/rollup-plugin-node-polyfills/polyfills/http-lib/capability.js (../storefront-remix/node_modules/rollup-plugin-node-polyfills/polyfills/http-lib/capability.js:39:45)
  at ../storefront-remix/apps/shop/dist/worker/index.js:14:56
  at ../../node_modules/rollup-plugin-node-polyfills/polyfills/http-lib/request.js (../storefront-remix/node_modules/rollup-plugin-node-polyfills/polyfills/http-lib/request.js:1:1)
  at ../storefront-remix/apps/shop/dist/worker/index.js:14:56
  at node-modules-polyfills:http (../storefront-remix/apps/shop/dist/worker/node-modules-polyfills:http:30:1)
  at ../storefront-remix/apps/shop/dist/worker/index.js:14:56
  at node-modules-polyfills-commonjs:http (../storefront-remix/apps/shop/dist/worker/node-modules-polyfills-commonjs:http:2:18)
  at ../storefront-remix/apps/shop/dist/worker/index.js:17:50
  at ../../node_modules/@mswjs/interceptors/lib/interceptors/ClientRequest/index.js (../storefront-remix/node_modules/@mswjs/interceptors/src/interceptors/ClientRequest/index.ts:1:1)
```

The current setup has this file, copied and very slightly updated from the remix-run example linked above:

```
import { setupServer } from 'msw/node'
import { handlers } from './msw-handlers'

export function startServer() {
  const server = setupServer(...handlers)
  server.listen({ onUnhandledRequest: 'warn' })
  console.log('MSW initialised')
}
```

And I've tried calling that function at the start of my `handleRequest` function in `app/entry.server.tsx`:

```
export default async function handleRequest(
  request: Request,
  responseStatusCode: number,
  responseHeaders: Headers,
  remixContext: EntryContext & { optimizely: OptimizelyLoadContext }
) {
  startServer()

  const markup = renderToString(
    <RemixServer context={remixContext} url={request.url} />
  )

  responseHeaders.set('Content-Type', 'text/html')

  return new Response('<!DOCTYPE html>' + markup, {
    status: responseStatusCode,
    headers: responseHeaders,
  })
}
```

I've also tried it at the top of `/server.ts` as well as in my route file (obviously it shouldn't be that).

The error makes it look like the problem is in the MSW code itself, which is worrying.

Does anyone know what to do here?

Answer (score 0):

It seems you've got the server-side Remix integration of MSW a bit wrong.

### TL;DR

Please follow [this Remix usage example](https://github.com/mswjs/examples-new/tree/4035459a12f32072d6b31e75572efb6cf3c056dd/examples/with-remix) that features MSW setup for both client-side and server-side. It will get you set up and running in no time

### More context

Calling `startServer` on `handleRequest` is simply incorrect. Remix calls `handleRequest` on *every incoming request*. MSW should be instantiated on the server-side **only once**. You can also raise an issue in whichever example you found this is as it's misleading and wrong to use MSW this way.

Instead, you have to enable MSW on the root scope of the `entry.server.jsx` file.

```js
// app/entry.server.jsx
import { enableApiMocking } from './mocks/node'
import { handlers } from './mocks/handlers'

if (process.env.NODE_ENV === 'development') {
  enableApiMocking(handlers)
}
```

> You **have** to import the `handlers` in `entry.server.jsx` explicitly as well. This is important. The way Remix re-evaluated modules on hot reloading requires this for the changes in `handlers` to propagate to Remix correctly.

Then, describe the `enableApiMocking` function:

```js
// mocks/node.js
import { setupServer } from 'msw/node'

export function enableApiMocking(handlers) {
  const existingServer = globalThis.mswServerInstance

  if (typeof existingServer !== 'undefined') {
    restart(existingServer, handlers)
  } else {
    start(setup(handlers))
  }
}

function setup(handlers) {
  const server = setupServer(...handlers)
  globalThis.mswServerInstance = server
  return server
}

function start(server) {
  server.listen()

  process
    .once('SIGTERM', () => server.close())
    .once('SIGINT', () => server.close())
}

function restart(server, handlers) {
  server.close()
  start(setup(handlers))
}
```

This is a bit verbose but the right approach for the server-side Remix integration of MSW to support hot reloading. I've proposed an easier way to do this but it's still being reviewed by the Remix team.